# Fortranのソースコードを自動で整形し、可読性を上げたい

Tags: fortran

古いFortranのソースコードを自動整形してくれるツールというものは、あるのでしょうか。検索してもいまいち見つからず、数値計算を専門にしていて、Fortranしか使わない人に実際に会って聞いたりしてますが、よい回答は得られませんでした。

大体古いFORTRAN77のコードとなると、全部大文字で、誰かが編集するたびに年月日と編集者がコメントで入り、またネストしたIF文やDOループも全部左詰めで書いていたりして、制御が追いにくく、こちらが読むたびに手でインデントをしていたりしたり、邪魔なコメントを削除しています（コメントは消しにくいでしょうが、単語の出現頻度から自動で消せそうな気もします。これは自作しないと無理かもしれませんが）。

イメージとしては、C言語でLinuxであれば
indent *.c
といった形で、まとめてやりたいのですが、おいおい自分で作るしかないのだろうとあきらめかけています。プラットフォームは問いませんので、何かご存知の方がいらっしゃったら、教えてください。

Comment: 色々オフラインで情報を集めていたら、emacsを使って、できることが確認できました。
http://qiita.com/lazynick/items/04d8e2b7386ae70d5dc7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FORTRAN 77 のみ対応した [floppy](http://www.netlib.org/floppy/) というツールがあるようです。また商用ですと [plusFORT の SPAG](http://www.polyhedron.com/products/fortran-tools/plusfort-with-spag/spag-fortran-code-restructuring.html)　が使えそうです。こちらは各バージョンに対応しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。SPAGはよさそうですが、高いですね。フリーでないのが残念です。